# REmove duplicate account from wrapper object salesforce

Tags: set, duplicates, salesforce, wrapper, apex

I am trying to remove duplicate account from my wrapper object.
But unable to get that.
Here is my apex class..Please help me to remove duplicate account from adding to the list.
This line is adding duplicate account ids.

allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( objContact.account.name, objContact.AccountId ));

```
Public with sharing class Customaccountlookupcontroller{

Public list<Customaccountlookupcontroller.AccountWrapper> allaccts{get;set;}
public string searchString{get;set;}
Public list<account> results{get;set;}
Public contact objcontact{get;set;}
Public list<id> accids;

public class AccountWrapper {
public String name {get; set;}
public Id accountId {get; set;}
public AccountWrapper(String name, String accountId) {
  this.name = name;     this.accountId = accountId;
  }
}
public Customaccountlookupcontroller() {
allaccts =  new list<Customaccountlookupcontroller.AccountWrapper>();
user u= [select id,contactId  from user  where id=:userinfo.getuserID()];
if(u.contactID !=null)
{
 Contact objContact =[select AccountId,Account.name,contact.name,(select AccountId,account.name from AccountContactRoles) from Contact where Id=: u.contactID];   
 for(AccountContactRole obj: objContact.AccountContactRoles)
 {   
   allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( obj.account.name, obj.AccountId ));
   allaccts.add(new AccountWrapper( objContact.account.name, objContact.AccountId ));
    }
       }
 System.debug('*******objcontact:'+allaccts);
         }
       }

public string getFormTag() {
return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('frm');
}

public string getTextBox() {
return System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('txt');
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define two methods in your wrapper "equals" and "hashCode" and use the data member of wrapper which you want to keep unique. In below code i have "name" in your code you can use "accountid"

```
public class TestWrapper{
    public String name {get; set;}
    public Integer val {get; set;}
    public TestWrapper(String name, Integer val) {
        this.name = name;     
        this.val = val;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        TestWrapper other=(TestWrapper) obj;
        return this.name==other.name;
    }

    public Integer hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Instead of List use Set of wrapper:

```
public TestData(){
    Set<TestWrapper> tlist = new Set<TestWrapper>();
    tlist.add(new TestWrapper('A',1));
    tlist.add(new TestWrapper('B',1));
    tlist.add(new TestWrapper('C',1));
    tlist.add(new TestWrapper('A',1));
    System.debug(tlist);
}
```

Hope it works!!!!